# Hash code, why is string and numeric key not good for memory address

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashcode

In the data structure lecture (and still happening right now), our lecturer explained that hash codes are useful for memory addresses.

That made sense, but then he added "except for numeric and string keys – Why?"

I thought the reason was because then we can no longer apply hash functions but according to him that is not true.

As we can either implement different hash function for strings or use integer representation of the memory addresses.

He claimed the reason is due to the fact that strings are array and numeric can be array type as well. And applying the hash function would only allocate part of that character to the 'bucket array'.

The thing is our lecturer isn't the guy who made the lecture note (He uses the previous lecturer's one last year) and I don't think what he said today is correct, Can someone enlighten me on this please?

Comment: What does "hash codes are useful for memory addresses" mean?

Comment: Hello, what he told us was that hash codes are used in integer casting (Suitable for keys of length less than or equal to the number of
bits of the integer type), memory address, and component sums

Comment: Without context, this whole discussion is incomprehensible.

Comment: Our class has just started on hash tables, nothing much done yet. We started off with the definition of hash fuction and hash table. Then lecture note stated why hash codes are useful. And it says "Memory address: We reinterpret the memory address of the key object as an integer (default hash code of all Java objects) Good in general, except for numeric and string keys – Why?"

Comment: Because numbers and strings are generally compared by content instead of identity, although of course that applies to many record types as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lecture notes you refer to come directly from Goodrich & Tamassia’s book (both the Algorithm design one and Data Structures). It discusses a variety of hash code functions - such as using the memory address of the object, using an integer cast, component sum, or polynomial accumulation. It notes that using the memory address of an object is “good in general, except for numeric and string keys”.

There are times when the hash code that maps an object to an integer based on its memory address is sufficient, even if that object is a string. However, **two objects with equal value** (a=‘hello’, b=‘hello’) **would not have the same hash code using this method, since they have different memory addresses.** The same applies for other objects such as numeric keys (a=10, b=10 are equal in value but not in memory address).

Consider a simple system which stores a password for a user as a hash code. If the user enters in a password, the string they entered in is hashed according to the same hash function and compared against the one which is stored. These two passwords have the same value (the one the user first created and the one they use to log in), so they should produce the same hash to successfully log in. Therefore, we would not want to use the memory address to map the string to an integer in this scenario.

Comment: Oh wow, may I ask how you were able to find where that content came from? were you happen to read that book when you saw this question?

Comment: The publisher of the book provides lecture slides which are often used (with some modification) by educators. In reading them I had a similar question about the phrasing which brought me here :)